# twisted: one client, many servers

Tags: python, twisted

I'm trying to use twisted to create a cluster of computers that run one program on a piece of a larger dataset.

My "servers" receive a chunk of data from the client and run command x on it.

My "client" connects to multiple servers giving them each a chunk of data and telling them what parameters to run command x with.

My question is: is there a way to set up the reactor loop to connect to many servers:

```
reactor.connectTCP('localhost', PORT, BlastFactory())
reactor.run()
```

or do I have to swap client and server in my paradigm?

Comment: "Connect to [whatever] clients" is not how TCP-IP works -- the client(s) do the connecting, the server(s) get connected _to_ (you can also have "peers" that are both servers _and_ clients, though few popular protocols except the peer-to-peer ones do that).

Comment: @Alex Martelli:  That's a type-o.  I'm still confusing clients and servers at this point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just call `connectTCP` multiple times.

The trick, of course, is that `reactor.run()` blocks "forever" (the entire run-time of your program) so you don't want to call *that* multiple times.

You have several options; you can set up a timed call to make future connections, or you can start new connections from events on your connection (like `connectionLost` or `clientConnectionFailed`).

Or, at the simplest, you can just set up multiple connection attempts before `reactor.run()` kicks off the whole show, like this:

```
for host in hosts:
    reactor.connectTCP(host, PORT, BlastFactory())
reactor.run()
```

Comment: I didn't know I could do that, wee!